# What is routers_match and layout_render in Magento 2.2.4 Profiler?

Tags: magento2, profiler

I'm new to Magento 2. Please help me to know the meaning and how can we reduce load time of routers_match and layout_render in Magento 2.2.4 Profiler?

Comment: Are you able to reduce the load time of above params in profile ? I am looking for same thing.